# Nuxt 3 Server with Pug for email templates

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, pug, nuxtjs3

I have created an endpoint with Nuxt 3 Server to send emails.

The email sending part is working great.

The styling of the email templates is done with Pug but I am having a hard time to get the path to the pug templates.

I suspect the issue is that the pug files are not being included in the build process.

When deployed to netlify which runs `yarn build` I get

`"ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '~/views/email/welcome.pug'"`

```js
async send(template, subject) {
  // 1) Render HTML based on a pug template
  const html = pug.renderFile(
    `~/views/email/${template}.pug`,
    {
      firstName: this.firstName,
      url: this.url,
      data: this.data,
      subject
    }
  );
}
```

My project structure looks like this.

[image]

What would be the best way to handle this?

Comment: It does work if you build locally? Maybe try with `@`, `/` or write an absolute path.

Comment: Yes it works locally if I do this `pug.renderFile('views/email/baseEmail.pug'`

Comment: But when I run `yarn build` and then run `yarn preview` (or deploy to Netlify) I get `"message": "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'views/email/baseEmail.pug'",`

Comment: `yarn build` is not for a static build, you should run `yarn generate`. But you probably need a Node server for emails anyway.

Comment: Yes that's right. If I run `yarn generate` there will be no server making using Nuxt server pointless. I managed to get it working for now by adding my pug template in a js file wrapped in string literals and then import it, then use `pug.render(pugTemplate...`. But there must be an easier way. I also tried to import the pug template using `import {pugTemplate} from './pugTemplate.pug'` but I got a rollup error. I think this could be solved with rollup and vite but I am not sure how.

Comment: If you need a server, then go for `yarn build` and host it somewhere with a Node.js server, like Heroku or alike. On top of the import issue of course.

Comment: That's essentially what I did. I deployed it to netlify, which runs yarn build. But that's where things went wrong and I posted this question. Do you think it would work on Heroku is there a difference compared to Netlify?

Comment: Netlify is for static websites (free service) only (**NO** Node.js), so only with `yarn generate`. Here, you need a server for your emails, hence `yarn build` and a place with a Node.js server running (paid service).

Comment: I deployed it to heroku and it works perfectly using `pug.renderFile('views/email/baseEmail.pug'` I actually prefer heroku and have used it a lot in the past but lately I have been using Netlify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to send emails, you will a Node.js server somewhere. You could use Heroku and push your code there, then use `yarn build && yarn start` there.

Should fix your issue.

PS: `yarn generate` is for SSG, Netlify can handle those apps for free but it will not come with all the server capabilities.

Comment: One thing I am wondering.. I have built several simple Nuxt apps with nuxt server endpoints and run them on Netlify without any problem until now. All of them are set to `yarn build`. From what I can tell it loads the server.js via server/index.mjs, pretty much identical to what you get when you run yarn preview.

So I am curious why you say you can only use Netlify with `yarn generate`

Comment: @AndyJamesN I'm not sure about server routes and what this one means exactly in terms of internals. Meanwhile, Nuxt3 is using Nitro and comes with a few things baked-in regarding optimization/build and generation. So, even if you do build with a specific target, it may still work with the other one depending on what you're actually using. But if you `yarn build`, `yarn preview` will run `node ./server/index.mjs`. If you run `yarn generate`, `yarn preview` will run `npx serve -s ./public`. Those 2 are totally different approaches overall. Docs: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/deploy/static-hosting